# In Clojure can I call a function that expects keys with a map?

Tags: clojure

Let's say I have

```
(defn test [ & {:keys [a b c]}]
   (println a)
   (println b)
   (println c))
```

What I want is to call test with a **map** `{:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}`.

This works:

```
(apply test [:a 1 :b 2 :c 3])
```

These do not:

```
(apply test {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
(apply test (seq {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}))
```

**EDIT**
So you can of course define the function like this also:

```
(defn test [{:keys [a b c]}] ; No & 
  (println a)
  (println b)
  (println c))
```

And then you can pass a map to it:

```
(test {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})
1
2
3
```

When learning clojure I had missed this was possible. Nevertheless if you ever come across a function defined by me or somebody like me then knowing how to pass a map to it could still be useful ;)

Comment: It is worth mentioning that you are trying to do some fancy destructuring. Also I am confused as to how you plan to use variadic (&) args here. If you do not have the variadic args, invoking test with the map will work as you want.

Comment: Agreed that the best choice is to not do this "keyword args" thing if you can help it. It's nice in certain unusual cases, but awkward to pass around from layer to layer. And it's easy to turn a seq of keyvals into a map, but as you saw it's not so simple to make a map into a seq of keyvals.

Comment: The [Library Coding Standards](http://dev.clojure.org/display/design/Library+Coding+Standards) suggest that unrolling arguments is better than requiring a map (if they're optional).

Comment: @JulienChastang Ooops, I always thought that the & was required to use :keys. Thanks for clearing up this misconception.

Comment: @amalloy Do you think keywords are evil in general or just my & {:keys ...} version?

Comment: Keywords are fine at the outermost, user-facing level of your API. But once you get deeper inside, unrolling and re-rolling them is just a pain and it's easier to pass around a map.

Comment: @amalloy Ok, got it. But the second form (no `&`) would still be ok, right, because there you can pass the map to the function(?)

Comment: @Paul Definitely. Though it's sorta a matter of style: some prefer `(defn foo [m] (let [{:keys [bar baz]} m] ...))` in some cases. I think for maps it's usually nice to "self-document" by destructuring in the arglists, but for sequences it's usually nicer to present a clean API and destructure internally.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
user> (apply list (mapcat seq {:a 1 :b [2 3 4]}))
(:a 1 :b [2 3 4])
```

Answer (score 3):

Any good reason not to define it like this in the first place?

```
(defn my-test [{:keys [a b c]}] ;; so without the &
   (println a)
   (println b)
   (println c))
```

and then call it like this?

```
(my-test {:a 10 :b 20 :c 30})
```

which outputs:

```
10
20
30
nil
```

Comment: Initially I wasn't aware that you can leave out the `&`. But if you encounter a function in the wild that you didn't write then knowing the solution to the above question can still be useful.

Answer (score 1):

This works, but is inelegant:

`(apply test (flatten (seq {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})))`

The reason `(apply test (seq {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3}))` doesn't work is that `(seq {:a 1 :b 2 :c 3})` returns `[[:a 1] [:b 2] [:c 3]]`, flatten takes care of this.

Better solutions?

Comment: Anything that doesn't involve `flatten` is better than this. What if my map is `{:a [1 2 3] :b [4 5 6]}`?